# AndEngine - sprite loop position from start of the screen to the end of the screen

Tags: android, loops, andengine, sprite

I'm creating a game in AndEngine for a school project and so far it's going good.

Here is a screenshot my game so far.
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvy0N.jpg)

I want the sprites to go from their original position to the end of the screen. Here is a screenshot of my attempt of doing that.
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKl3O.jpg)

Here is my for loop that creates the world

```
for(int x = 0; x < camera.getWidth()/GameManager.lengthOfTile; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < camera.getHeight()/GameManager.lengthOfTile; y++){
            if(y == 0){
                worldSprite[currentTile] = new Sprite(0, 0, grassTR, this.activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                worldSprite[currentTile].setPosition(xPos[x], y * GameManager.lengthOfTile);
                worldSprite[currentTile].registerEntityModifier(new MoveXModifier((float) (0.5 * x), xPos[x], -GameManager.lengthOfTile));
                scene.attachChild(worldSprite[currentTile]);
                updateTile();
            }
            if(y >= 1 && y <= 6){
                worldSprite[currentTile] = new Sprite(0, 0, roadTR, this.activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                worldSprite[currentTile].setPosition(xPos[x], y * GameManager.lengthOfTile);
                worldSprite[currentTile].registerEntityModifier(new MoveXModifier((float) (0.5 * x), xPos[x], -GameManager.lengthOfTile));
                scene.attachChild(worldSprite[currentTile]);
                updateTile();
            }
            if(y == 7){
                worldSprite[currentTile] = new Sprite(0, 0, grassTR, this.activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                worldSprite[currentTile].setPosition(xPos[x], y * GameManager.lengthOfTile);
                worldSprite[currentTile].setRotation(180);
                worldSprite[currentTile].registerEntityModifier(new MoveXModifier((float) (0.5 * x), xPos[x], -GameManager.lengthOfTile));
                scene.attachChild(worldSprite[currentTile]);
                updateTile();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see the `registerEntityModifier(new MoveXModifier((float) (0.5 * x), xPos[x], -GameManager.lengthOfTile));` is not the right approach to accomplish my goals which are to sync all the sprites to go in a constant velocity and when the sprites have reached their destination I want them to reset their position to the start of the screen.

I would really appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: You can nest modifiers. There is LoopModifier and many others. Give them a try. I can't expand my answer because I'm on my phone

Comment: Looking your screenshots, you may want to take a look at parallax background or background modifiers

Comment: Thanks, I will look into parallax background and background modifiers and update my post when I'm done.